# PullToRefresh Library causing LayoutInflater error - Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having some trouble with getting this library to work. The library in question is PullToRefresh and according to Android Studio there are some file errors within the library which is causing it to not work properly. The project can be compiled fine but as soon as it tries to run it on my devices it brings up the "has stopped working" and the LogCat spews out some information about the LayoutInflater being incorrect. Other people have this working fine so I doubt it is the library with errors although if someone could help me fix this I would be grateful. I have got actionbarsherlock being used as a library and it works perfectly and I tried removing actionbarsherlock just to see if that was the problem and the error still happened.

This is what android studio is saying as to why the library cannot be used. Ask for a logcat if you want it.

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView (Open Class, Show Exception)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  
Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.LoadingLayout.<init>(LoadingLayout.java:83)   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.internal.RotateLoadingLayout.<init>(RotateLoadingLayout.java:42)   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase$AnimationStyle.createLoadingLayout(PullToRefreshBase.java:1328)   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.createLoadingLayout(PullToRefreshBase.java:587)   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.init(PullToRefreshBase.java:1108)   
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshBase.<init>(PullToRefreshBase.java:113)   
 at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView.<init>(PullToRefreshScrollView.java:33)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original   
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
```